# netcat listerning pod in kubernetes namespace unable to connect

Tags: kubernetes, netcat

I am running kubernetes v 19.4 with weave-net ( image: weaveworks/weave-npc:2.7.0)
There are no network policies active in the default namespace

I want to run a netcat listener on pod1 port 8080, and want to connect to pod1 port 8080 by pod2

```
[root@node01 ~]# kubectl run pod1 -i -t --image=ubuntu -- /bin/bash
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
root@pod1:/# apt update ; apt install netcat-openbsd -y            
........
root@pod1:/# nc -l -p 8080
```

I verify the port is listening on pod1 by :

```
root@node01 ~]# kubectl exec -i -t pod1 -- /bin/bash 
root@pod1:/# apt install net-tools -y 
...........
root@pod1:/# netstat -tulpen  
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          213960     263/nc

root@pod1:/# ifconfig             
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1376
        inet 10.32.0.3  netmask 255.240.0.0  broadcast 10.47.255.255
        ether a2:b9:3e:bc:6e:25  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 8429  bytes 17438639 (17.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4217  bytes 284639 (284.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I install pod2 witn netcat on it:

```
[root@node01 ~]# kubectl run pod2 -i -t --image=ubuntu -- /bin/bash 
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
root@pod2:/# apt update ; apt install netcat-openbsd -y
```

I test my netcat listener on pod1 from pod2:

```
root@pod2:/# nc 10.32.0.3 8080
....times out
```

So i decided to create a service of port 8080 on pod1:

```
kubectl expose pod pod1 --port=8080 ; kubectl get svc ; kubectl get netpol 

[root@node01 ~]# kubectl expose pod pod1 --port=8080 ; kubectl get svc 
service/pod1 exposed
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
apache       ClusterIP   10.104.218.123   <none>        80/TCP     20d
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP    21d
nginx        ClusterIP   10.98.221.196    <none>        80/TCP     13d
pod1         ClusterIP   10.105.194.196   <none>        8080/TCP   2s
No resources found in default namespace.
```

Retry from pod2 now by service:

```
ping pod1   
PING pod1.default.svc.cluster.local (10.105.194.196) 56(84) bytes of data.

root@pod2:/# nc pod1 8080
....times out
```

I also tried this with the regular netcat package.

For good measure i try to expose port 8080 on the pod as nodeport:

```
root@node01 ~]# kubectl delete svc pod1 ; kubectl expose pod pod1 --port=8080 --type=NodePort ; kubectl get svc 

So when i try to access that port from outside kubernetes i am unable to connect, for good measure i also test the ssh port to verify my base connectivity is ok
user@DESKTOP-7TIH9:~$ nc -zv 10.10.70.112 30743
nc: connect to 10.10.70.112 port 30743 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
user@DESKTOP-7TIH9:~$ nc -zv 10.10.70.112 22
Connection to 10.10.70.112 22 port [tcp/ssh] succeeded!
```

Can anybody tell me if i am doing something, have the wrong expectation or advice me how to proceed.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there any firewall that might block you connection? Can you ping the pods from inside one of them? I've tried it with calico installed and everything works OK.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to solve this i somehow decided to enable the firewall on the k8s hosts.
This lead me to a broken cluster. I decided to reinit the cluster, make sure all the fw ports are opened. Including this one : https://www.weave.works/docs/net/latest/faq#ports

All is working now1